# javascript - Makes a Scrollbar appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem here is that after a script that demonstrates a count down timer there is a not needed scrollbar that appears and is not able to scroll because all the components are visible and things are good, except the appearance of the scrollbar.

My css is below :

```
.Height75Percentage{
    height:75.92%
}
.ResultsDiv {
    position: relative
    float: left
    text-align: center
    width: 100%
    overflow: auto
    background
    margin-top
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgbal(0,0,0,0.25)
    -moz-box-shadow 0px 0px 10px 5px rgbal(0,0,0,0.25)
    box-shadow
    height
}

/* Inherited from body */
body {
    font-size:14px
    font-family: Georgia
    color:#808081
}
```

The script is in the code like this : `<script src="Scripts/coundown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
and the code is :

```
var offset = 1;
var seconds = 60 - offset;
function secondPass() {
var remainingSeconds = seconds;
if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
}
document.getElementById('MainContent_countdownValue').innerHTML = remainingSeconds + "”";
if (seconds == 0) {

    document.getElementById('MainContent_countdownValue').innerHTML = "60" + "”";
    seconds = 60 - offset;
} else {
    seconds--;
}
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPass()', 1000);
```

Comment: share a minimal working code which replicates this issue and you'll get help

Comment: It sounds like you need a more [responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) approach, if you can't figure out whether the content is inside or not. Also your CSS isn't valid and you need to post your markup if you want help.

Comment: Mostly its because the scrollbar appears inside some other element, like a children element. Check twice if its really the element, which overflows...

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Thank tou very much I will get back with edit!!

Comment: I have posted the whole css

Comment: Hello Mich Kal. I am affraid this CSS is not valid... There is no ; and the content seems not a usual CSS with "property:value;"  Did you write it on your own ? Can you also add the corresponding HTML code of your page (at least, the usefull part).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is a bit funky and hard to make sense of but in general here is how you hide the scrollbar on a div (Here is a link to a demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sarkism/nv89zy4a/)

```css
.description {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(100% + 17px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <div class="inner">
    <h4>Description</h4>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I will re-edit my question because the problem is something different finally.

Comment: sorry but the question has changed, due to my investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set a fixed height for your parent component which causes scrollbars appeared.

Can just use `height: auto;`